# How can I download files from an https URI in android phonegap application?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

how to download files with https protocol in android ? I'm try to use it, but keep getting an error.

My download code:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
          fileTransfer.download(
                task_url,
                fileListDir + fileName,
            function(entry) {
                mylog("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
            },
            function(error) {
                mylog("download error source " + error.source);
                mylog("download error target " + error.target);
                mylog("upload error code" + error.code);
            });
```

My log

> 11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):
>   {"target":"/mnt/sdcard/task1/Picture_4.jpg","source":"https://91.228.199.95/ksiywFac63f2hs/fotos.gleb/Picture_4.jpg","code":3}
>   11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found. 11-19 13:56:13.339:
>   E/FileTransfer(17969):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:477)
>   11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:328)
>   11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:185)
>   11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
>   11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:378)
>   11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
>   11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:152)
>   11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):    at
>   org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.download(FileTransfer.java:486) 11-19
>   13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):  at
>   org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.execute(FileTransfer.java:88) 11-19
>   13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):  at
>   org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:231)
>   11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019) 11-19 13:56:13.339:
>   E/FileTransfer(17969): Caused by:
>   java.security.cert.CertificateException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found. 11-19 13:56:13.339:
>   E/FileTransfer(17969):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:161)
>   11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:664)
>   11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native
>   Method) 11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:474)
>   11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):    ... 10 more 11-19
>   13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969): Caused by:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found. 11-19 13:56:13.339:
>   E/FileTransfer(17969):    at
>   org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:207)
>   11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):    at
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:197)
>   11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:156)
>   11-19 13:56:13.339: E/FileTransfer(17969):    ... 13 more

Comment: Please share the logs of the error...

Answer (score 4):

Answer is change old cordova to cordova 2.2.0 and write in the code true, some this

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
      fileTransfer.download(
            task_url,
            fileListDir + fileName,
        function(entry) {
            mylog("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        },
        function(error) {
            mylog("download error source " + error.source);
            mylog("download error target " + error.target);
            mylog("upload error code" + error.code);
        }, true);
```

And this is work!!! Thanks Simon Mac Donald!!

Comment: It should be mentioned though that this deactivates the certificate check competely and is not recommended for production usage. See: [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md) - trustAllHosts: Optional parameter, defaults to false. If set to true, it accepts all security certificates. This is useful since Android rejects self-signed security certificates. Not recommended for production use. Supported on Android and iOS. (boolean)